# Describing a group of people who lie down in a public place to send a political message

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I was walking through the square, and I came upon a group of people all lying on the ground. Each had a printout on their chest with a political message, and nobody was moving.

[image: Photo of many people lying on their backs on a flat concrete expanse]

What word or phrase could best be used to describe a group of people who lie down in a public place in order to send a political message?

Comment: This looks like a *"lie-in"* protest demonstration - sometimes also called a *"die-in"*.  The protestors lie down in an area, representing dead people, sometimes having signs or banners on their bodies, as your picture appears to show. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die-in

Comment: fainting by numbers

Comment: Looks like this might be a [flash mob.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_mob)

Comment: Everybody do [the flop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5inD4XWz4U).

Comment: Protesters or not, it's hard to describe them as "activists."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answered very nicely by [Kristina Lopez](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/25824/kristina-lopez) in a comment:

> This looks like a "*lie-in*" protest demonstration - sometimes also called a "*die-in*". The protestors lie down in an area, representing dead people, sometimes having signs or banners on their bodies, as your picture appears to show. [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die-in)

Comment: Really though, the question asks what do you call the group of people.  The people are *participating* in a ***lie-in*** but the people are *called* ***protesters***.  But of course *protesters* is not sufficiently distinct to describe only *lie-in protesters*

Comment: So, _lie-in protesters_ it is then. Not be be confused with lyin' protesters.

Comment: You can also call them *demonstrators*.  I like it better because they're not necessarily *against* something.  They might be demonstrating *for* something.

Answer (score 5):

From *Oxford Dictionaries* the following definitions of *satyagrahi* and *satyagraha* :

> [***satyagrahi***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satyagrahi)
>
> NOUN
>
> A person who practises the policy of satyagraha:
>   ‘as a satyagrahi, suffering in the path of freedom and justice was part of his creed’
>
> **[satyagraha](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satyagraha)**
>   NOUN
>
> [mass noun] A policy of passive political resistance, especially that advocated by Mahatma Gandhi against British rule in India.
>
> - ‘This is where Gandhi developed his concept of satyagraha, translated in the west as passive resistance that, in the end, influenced the whole of the colonial world.’
>
> **Origin**
>   Sanskrit, from *satya* truth + *āgraha* obstinacy.m

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the commonly used contemporary terminology, it seems to me that your inquiry has been answered. So I feel you may be searching for a new phrase that is a nuanced descriptive of a "lie-in" or "die-in" (as suggested in your title, "describing a group of people...")

One could riff on the old by creating something new:

***"vie-in"***:

Vie, as in:

> [battle](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vie?s=t)

Battle, as in:

> [to try to overcome; struggle against or contend with](http://www.yourdictionary.com/battle)

The demonstrators are ***vying*** to *overcome* some perceived injustice,  ***vying*** in a *struggle* for a voice, ***vying*** as an act of *contention* against powers whose eyes and ears are closed to their needs or opinions or rights.  They are ***vying*** with the words affixed to their very bodies, with their bodies affixed to the very ground, as an expression of the power that a dead body holds ubiquitously, as a spector which must be seen, acknowledged, respected, and responded to.  So that their voices may be seen, acknowledged, respected and responded to.

References:

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/battle)

[YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/battle)